# Arraylist bind in listview

Tags: android

`ArrayList` is not binding with `ListView`. In my Google API at line

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm getting `NullPointerException`. What's wrong? I don't understand it. How to solve this problem?

**Activity**:

```
package app.googlemap.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import app.googlemap.R;
import app.googlemap.Response.BackgroudAsyn;
import app.googlemap.Response.Json;
import app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse;
import app.googlemap.activity.MainActivity;

/**
 * Created by Fame ITC on 17-May-16.
 */
public class GoogleApi extends Activity {

    static  ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    AdapterGoogle adapter;
    ListView lv;
    Json json;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_api);
        FindView();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();
        new BackgroudAsyn().execute(this);

    }

    public void FindView(){
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

    }

    public void api(String response ){
        if(response != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            try {
                     progressDialog.hide();
                    json = gson.fromJson(response,Json.class);
                    String ok = json.getStatus().toString();
                    String abs = json.getResults().toString();
                 //   tv.setText(abs);
                    Log.d("okkkk", "api: " + ok );
                    Log.d("result... == ", "api: " + json.getResults());
                    adapter = new AdapterGoogle(this , GoogleApi.this , json.getResults());
                    Log.d("okkkk", "api: " + adapter );
                    if(adapter != null) {
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        // setupAdapter(mdata);
                    }

                Log.e("RegistrationActivity", "Got Response:-" + ok);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Googleapi", "Error In Response:-" + e);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setupAdapter(ArrayList<RegionResponse> mData){

        if (mData.size() > 0 && mData != null){

            Log.d("Tag .. ", "setupAdapter: " +  mData);
            adapter = new AdapterGoogle(this , GoogleApi.this , mData);
            Log.d("TAG ....", "setupAdapter: .............." + adapter);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }


}
```

***This is adapter class***

```
public class AdapterGoogle extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<RegionResponse> result = null ;

    public AdapterGoogle(Context context , Activity activity , ArrayList<RegionResponse> result){
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.result = result;
        Log.d("jk", "AdapterGoogle: .." + result);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return result.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return result.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_json_list, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
            mViewHolder.category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            mViewHolder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);

        } else {

            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        mViewHolder.category.setText(result.get(position).getName());
        mViewHolder.id.setText(result.get(position).getPlace_id());
        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        TextView category, id;
    }
}
```

***Logcat Error***

```
    06-22 18:02:09.611 24405-24405/? D/result... ==: api: [app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@41a16b68, app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@41a0f5e8, app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@418a84c0, app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@418c8910, app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@418cdb38, app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@41a3c6a0]
06-22 18:02:09.611 24405-24405/? D/jk: AdapterGoogle: ..[app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@41a16b68, app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@41a0f5e8, app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@418a84c0, app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@418c8910, app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@418cdb38, app.googlemap.Response.RegionResponse@41a3c6a0]
06-22 18:02:09.611 24405-24405/? D/okkkk: api: ***app.googlemap.activity.AdapterGoogle@418b8900
06-22 18:02:09.611 24405-24405/? E/Googleapi: Error In Response:-java.lang.NullPointerException***
06-22 18:02:09.611 24405-24405/? D/HAWAII_EGL: eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 24405
06-22 18:02:09.611 24405-24405/? D/HAWAII_EGL: eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x55aba560, android window 0x54c2fad0, Thread: 24405
06-22 18:02:10.011 1386-1516/? D/java.hwcomposer: FBDevice::vsync called 61 times
06-22 18:02:10.292 1808-1846/? D/WifiStateMachine: handleMessage: E msg.what=131155
06-22 18:02:10.292 1808-1846/? D/WifiStateMachine: processMsg: ConnectedState
06-22 18:02:10.292 1808-1846/? D/WifiStateMachine: processMsg: L2ConnectedState
06-22 18:02:10.292 4517-4517/? D/wpa_supplicant: RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=11): 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c
06-22 18:02:10.292 4517-4517/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
06-22 18:02:10.302 4517-4517/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: survey data missing!
```

Comment: your `activity_google_api ` contains `ListView` by id `listview`?

Comment: Above message + make sure you call ```setupAdapter```  after ```FindView()```.

Comment: yes Listview is by id listview

Comment: Can you post logcat?

Comment: post your exact logcat error message

Comment: I update Error which come when --- this line execute  lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I assume you are calling your api method inside your asynctask. Since, from what you have given us, I can't tell you whats wrong, do you mind also posting the async task itself?

Comment: And btw, your NPE has something to do with the listview

Comment: post your activity_google_api.xml file

Comment: No problem in any other file bro after one hour my interview please check in this file